# Make button delete parent.parent.parent element without using ID in Anuglar (click)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am making a site where the user should be able to delete li-elements on-click:
The li elements are inside bootstrap-containers, therefor it is the container with all its children I want to delete. The button itself is also inside the container.

Here is the HTML-code:

```
<ol class="secondLevel">
<li>
    <h3>Implementasjoner / forbedringer foregående periode</h3>
                                
    <ul #implementasjoner id="implementasjoner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <li>
                        <p>Supportsaker</p>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="????">Slett</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
    <button (click)="addLi(implementasjoner.id)" class="btn btn-secondary">Legg til punkt</button>
</li>
</ol>
```

I want the button with the (click)="???" to delete its own parent.parent.parent element on click, without using ID etc (this is because these elements are autogenerated and genrating unique IDs will be hard.

Is there any angular-way of doing this? Like using parent().parent().parent().remove() etc?

Btw, the autogenerating code looks like this:

```
addLi(olId: string) {
    var el = document.getElementById(olId);
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    var row = document.createElement("div");
    var col9 = document.createElement("div");
    var col3 = document.createElement("div");
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var text = document.createElement("p");
    btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-secondary deleteMe')
    container.setAttribute('class', 'container');\
    row.setAttribute('class', 'row');
    col3.setAttribute('class', 'col-lg-3');
    col9.setAttribute('class', 'col-lg-9')
    text.setAttribute('id', 'ptags');
    text.setAttribute('style', ' font-size: 1rem')
    text.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
    text.innerHTML = "skiv tekst her";
    btn.innerHTML = "Slett"
    node.appendChild(text);
    col9.appendChild(node);
    col3.appendChild(btn);
    row.appendChild(col9);
    row.appendChild(col3);
    container.appendChild(row);
    el.appendChild(container);
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can just through the parent of button 2 times and delete that node

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ol class="secondLevel">
        <li>
            <h3>Implementasjoner / forbedringer foregående periode</h3>

            <ul #implementasjoner id="implementasjoner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <li>
                                <p>Supportsaker</p>
                            </li>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="deleteParent()">Slett</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
            <button (click)="addLi(implementasjoner.id)" class="btn btn-secondary">Legg til punkt</button>
        </li>
    </ol>

    <script>
        function deleteParent(){
            var elementParent = event.target.parentNode
            for(let i = 1; i < 3;i++ ){
                elementParent = elementParent.parentNode
            }
            elementParent.remove()
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A solution almost equal to yours solved it for me:  deleteLi(e: Event) {
        let parent = (<HTMLElement>e.target).parentElement;
        parent = parent.parentElement;
        parent = parent.parentElement;
        parent.remove();
        console.log("ok");
        //btn.parentNode.
    }